# How to extract response data in Gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I'm new with gatling and I have problem that I can't resolve by myself. I have to send request and after that I have to catch data from response. I can send request using get method, but I don't have idea how to extract data from response. Do you have any ideas how to do this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please edit the question and provide the code sample for others to see and understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I did this using check clause

```
          http("Poll")
                .get(Configuration.URL )
                .queryParam("applicationId", Configuration.APPLICATION_ID)
                .check(status.is(200))
                .check(status.saveAs("statusCode"))                     
                .check(xpath("//myRunTimeInfo").saveAs("runtimeInfoStatus"))                    
                .check(xpath("//status").saveAs("responseStatus")))
              .pause(Configuration.THINK_TIME second)
```

xpath : will do a search in your response using xpath specifications